# Adding an Object to a collection

Tags: java, object, hashmap, addition

I am learning Hashmaps in Java, so I have a simple java program that creates an account. My problem is when it comes to storing the new accounts in a collection, I am trying to do it using a hashmap but just can't figure out where to go.

```
HashMap<String,CurrentAccount> m = new HashMap<String,String>();
if (Account.validateID(accountID)) {
    CurrentAccount ca = new CurrentAccount(cl,accountID, sortCode, 0);
```

I am unsure of the next stage to add this account to the hashmap I have tried a couple of different ways but always end up with an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error with your instantiation statement. The map's type is `HashMap<String, CurrentAccount>`, but you are instantiating `HashMap<String,String>`.

To fix this, change your instantiation statement to correspond to the map's type, like the following:

```
HashMap<String, CurrentAccount> m = new HashMap<String, CurrentAccount>();
```

Or if you are using JDK 1.7+, you could use diamond notation instead (see [Generic Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) for more information):

```
HashMap<String, CurrentAccount> m = new HashMap<>();
```

---

In order to add items to the map, you can use [Map#put(K, V)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29):

```
m.put(accountID, ca);
```

In order to get a value, you can use [Map#get(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
CurrentAccount ca = m.get(accountID);
```

See [JDK 1.7 Map documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for more information about maps.

---

As for the question made by the OP in the comments of this answer, in order to access the map (or any other type) in multiple methods, it has to be declared as a class field:

```
public class TestClass {
    Map<String, CurrentAccount> accountMap;

    public TestClass() {
        accountMap = new HashMap<String, CurrentAccount>();
    }

    public void method1() {
        // You can access the map as accountMap
    }

    public void method2() {
        // You can also acces it here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense now! My only other question is, say I have done all this in one function, is it then possible to call a value from the hashmap in another function?

Comment: You will have to have the hash map declared as a field of the class. I will update my answer to include an example.

Comment: Thanks very much think I've got the hang of this now! Cheers!

Comment: Sorry for another question, but I followed your edit above, works great until I use the accountMap.get(accountID) in another function and I receive accountId cannot be resolved?

Comment: You should learn a little bit more about scopes, check this article out: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html :-)

Answer (score 1):

The map declaration is incorrect, as you're typing the value to two different objects. Change the declaration to:

```
Map<String,CurrentAccount> m = new HashMap<String,CurrentAccount>();
```

Then, presuming the `accountID` value is a string, it should be as simple as...

```
m.put( accountID, ca );
```

Altogether you'll have:

```
Map<String,CurrentAccount> m = new HashMap<String,CurrentAccount>();

if (Account.validateID(accountID)) {
    CurrentAccount ca = new CurrentAccount(cl,accountID, sortCode, 0);
    m.put( accountID, ca );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not compile because you try to initialize the hasmap bound to the type String and Account to an hashmap of type String String for (key and value type)

```
HashMap<String, CurrentAccount> accountsMap = new Hashmap<String, String>()
```

should be

```
HashMap<String, CurrentAccount> accountsMap = new Hashmap<String, CurrentAccount>()
```

The first argument is the type for the key value the second is the type of the associated value for the key

To find a value within your hashmap you can use the following code snipped

```
 for (String key : accountsMap.keySet().iterator()) {
      CurrentAccount current = accounts.get(key);
 }
```

where accountsMap is your HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Use `put(key, value);` See [HashMap javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

```
m.put("SomeIdentifierString", ca);
```

Then whenever you want to access that particular object. Use the key to obtain it

```
CurrentAccount account = m.get("SomeIdentifierString");
```

If you want to iterate through the entire map to get key and values you can do this

```
for (Map.Entry<String, CurrentAccount> entry : m.entrySet()){
    String s = entry.getKey();
    CurrentAccount accuont = entry.getValue();
    // do something with them
}
```